# MySQL - Getting number of days a row remained the same

Tags: mysql

I have a website which tracks player statistics for an online game. One of the functions I'm trying to build is getting the player's clan history. The table that holds this info looks like this:

```
PLAYERID --|-- CLANTAG -|- UPDATETIME
-----------------------------------------------
XXXXXXXX --|-- [XXXXX] -|- 0000-00-00 00:00:00
```

The UPDATETIME is the date and time my crawler visited the game's API and got the info, and it's what I'm basing the time spent in a certain clan on.

I have this query, but it only gets the date the user entered a clan. What I couldn't figure out is how to get the earliest date he had that CLANTAG and the latest:

```
SELECT CLANTAG, UPDATETIME FROM account_stats WHERE PLAYERID = "XXXXXXXXX" GROUP BY CLANTAG
```

Another problem is that a user might have left a clan and then joined it again, and the query I made above would just bundle them together, so I'm completely lost :/

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Provide sample data and desired output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get earliest and latest dates per group you can use `MIN()` and `MAX()` aggregate functions

```
SELECT playerid, clantag, 
       MIN(updatetime) earliest_time,
       MAX(updatetime) latest_time
  FROM Table1
 WHERE playerid = 1
 GROUP BY playerid, clantag
```

Sample output:

```
| PLAYERID | CLANTAG |              EARLIEST_TIME |                 LATEST_TIME |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|        1 |       1 | May, 20 2013 12:00:00+0000 | July, 03 2013 15:00:00+0000 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9d17b/1)** demo

Comment: @LucasvonMecheln Did it help? Do you need more help with your question?